# Using VectorDrawableCompat

Tags: android, vector, support-vector-compat

In order to use an SVG file in my android project, I have to use vector compat.

First I converted my SVG file into a vector according to http://a-student.github.io/SvgToVectorDrawableConverter.Web/

Then I followed the official blog http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html

So here is my build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 22
        versionName "2.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    [...]
}
```

and in my xml I use this

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/dark_grey"
    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/login_margin">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/info_about_app"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/back_login"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/vector"/>  <-- Important line
```

and my vector looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:auto="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:width="425dp"
        android:height="252dp"
        android:viewportHeight="504"
        android:viewportWidth="850"
        auto:height="252dp"
        auto:viewportHeight="504"
        auto:viewportWidth="850"
        auto:width="425dp"
        tools:ignore="NewApi">
    <group
        android:translateY="-548.3622"
        auto:translateY="-548.3622">
```

No problem with preview in Android Studio, but when I try to run my app, I get the following error

```
Error:(2) No resource identifier found for attribute 'viewportHeight' in package 'xxx'
```

I think this error is due to bad ids backport but it is the role of

```
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

android plugin for gradle ==> 2.1.0-beta1
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: `auto:` is used for backport and `android:` for API > 21. I'm not sur I should remove one of both

Comment: Ok you're absolutely right. `auto:` has to be removed otherwise you get this kind of error (and backport still works).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove this line:

```
auto:viewportHeight="504"
```

this is what `No resource identifier found for attribute 'viewportHeight'` suggests me.

OR that you didn't import the support vector compat library.
But I'm inclined to think you did.